# What is the difference between category, group, and item type in HCL OneTest Data?

Tags: attributes, schema, grouping, categories

While creating schema in HCL OneTest Data, I came across the terms as Category, Group, and Item Type. Can anyone help me with understanding these terms in HCL OneTest Data?

Answer (score 0):

**Category**: A category type is used for inheritance and for organizing other types in a schema. For example, you might have a category named "OrderField" to organize the different kinds of order fields in your schema.

**Group**: A group type represents a complex data object that consists of other objects. For example, "FullName" is a group type that contains the components: FirstName, MiddleInitial, and LastName.

**Item**: An item type represents a simple data object that does not consist of other objects. It is a default class of schema.